# How to handle a long click event on wear compose?

Tags: android, wear-os

I use the **Wear Compose Version 1.2.1**, which can handle `onLongClick` event with Modifier.combinedClickable(), but after the **Wear Compose Version 1.3.x** does not handle the long click event.

I think the feature has changed, but I don't know how to modify my code. Can anyone please suggest how can I convert the below-mentioned code for the **Wear Compose Version 1.2.1,**

```
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(48.dp)
        .width(48.dp)
        .padding(2.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Black)
        .combinedClickable(
            interactionSource = remember {
                MutableInteractionSource()
            },
            indication = null,
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    context.getString(R.string.long_press_to_stop),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            },
            onLongClick = {
                Log.v("STOP", "onLongClick")
                // --- stop action ---
            },
        ),
    onClick = { },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.primaryButtonColors(backgroundColor =  Color.Black),
    enabled = true
) {
    Icon(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_stop_24),
        contentDescription = "Stop",
        tint = Color.LightGray
    )
}
```

The dependency section of my **build.gradle.kts**, just change the version number, then change the behaviour.

```
//val wearComposeVersion = "1.2.1"           // works OK
val wearComposeVersion = "1.3.0"             // does not handle long click event
implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-material:$wearComposeVersion")
implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-foundation:$wearComposeVersion")
implementation("androidx.wear.compose:compose-navigation:$wearComposeVersion")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

In a nutshell:

1. Add a `Box` as the root content of the `Button`.
2. Add the `combinedClickable` modifier to the `Box`, with the `onLongClick`.
3. `clearAndSetSemantics` from `Button` in order to add `onLongClick` for accessibility.

```kotlin
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val enabled = true
    val onClick = { /* your code */ }
    val onLongClick = { /* your code */ }
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(DefaultButtonSize)
            .clearAndSetSemantics {
                role = Role.Button
                this.contentDescription = contentDescription
                if (!enabled) {
                    disabled()
                }
                this.onClick(action = {
                    onClick()
                    true
                })
                if (onLongClick != null) {
                    this.onLongClick(action = {
                        onLongClick()
                        true
                    })
                }
            },
        enabled = enabled,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .combinedClickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null, // From material Button
                    enabled = enabled,
                    onClick = onClick,
                    onLongClick = onLongClick,
                    role = Role.Button,
                ),
        ) {
            // your content here
        }
    }
```

You can see how it was done in [Button](https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/101ef640b5a0b63f888f33f71c8f17f2556d9ac9/compose-material/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/compose/material/Button.kt).

#### Alternative solution

Use [Button](https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/101ef640b5a0b63f888f33f71c8f17f2556d9ac9/compose-material/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/compose/material/Button.kt) component from [Horologist](https://github.com/google/horologist) [Compose Material](https://github.com/google/horologist/tree/101ef640b5a0b63f888f33f71c8f17f2556d9ac9/compose-material) library.

Dependency:

```kotlin
implementation "com.google.android.horologist:horologist-compose-material:<version>"
```

Import:

```kotlin
import com.google.android.horologist.compose.material.Button
```

Usage:

```
Button(
    id = R.drawable.baseline_stop_24,
    contentDescription = "Stop",
    onClick = { /* your code */ },
    onLongClick = { /* your code */ },
)
```

#### Context

> Wear Compose Version 1.3.x does not handle the long click event.

Yes, as per [findings](https://github.com/google/horologist/issues/1822#issuecomment-1880827920) of a member of the Wear Compose team:

> it's not possible to add now another clickable outside of the component ( eg extend Chip or Button externally and add other callbacks like LongClick) - for that we have to rewrite the component itself ( by using combinedClickable or other modifiers) .

Be mindful that the solution above is tailored for `Button` component. There are more steps for other components with inner paddings like `Chip` and `Card` as per this [comment](https://github.com/google/horologist/issues/1822#issuecomment-1894417911).